How to display user role in WooCommerce Order
I have created a user role called wholesaler which allows me to separate my normal clients with our partners. Is there a way to display the user role somewhere in the WooCommerce order in the Wordpress admin panel? So whenever I open the order I can easily see if the user is wholesaler or normal customer.
